# Как разорвать цикл while True?

Tags: python, while

Не получается разорвать цикл `while True` в python. Реализовал простенький таймер для основного проекта, только проблема в том, что после выполнения программа не останавливается.
Вот код:

```py
from time import *

sets = int(input("Введіть кількість сетів = "))
exr = int(input("Введіть кількість вправ ="))
work_time = int(input("Введіть час роботи = "))
rest_time = int(input("Введіть час відпочинку = "))

while True:
    while exr != 0:
        while work_time != 0:
            sleep(1)
            work_time -= 1
            print("До перерви залишилось ", work_time)
        
        while rest_time != 0:
            sleep(1)
            rest_time -= 1
            print("Час до наступої вправи", rest_time)
```

1. Читал про операторы циклов, но на практике они не помогают
2. Смотрел подобные вопросы на стаке, но не помогло

Я не являюсь опытным программистом, даже джуном, может можно реализовать данную программу без `while True`, подскажите как? Программа является таймером для тренировок, нужно чтобы  код выполнился и программа остановилась. Как я выяснил цикл не прерывается в этом основная проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант можно создать переменную типа `Boolean` и задать ей изначальное значение `True`. При завершении вашего таймера можно в цикле поменять эту переменную на `False` и цикл остановится

Пример:

```
work = True

while work:
    # Тут делаем таймер
    # И после того, как он закончился
    work = False
```

Comment: Спасибо,  я внимательно перечитал код и выяснил что проблема в условии цикла

Answer (score 5):

Можно обернуть весь `while True` в функцию, и для прерывания использовать `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, что вы хотите сделать, но судя по тому, что тут имеется, ни цикл `while True`, ни цикл `while(exr!=0)` ни переменные `sets` и `exr` тут вообще не требуются:

```
from time import *

work_time = int(input("Введіть час роботи = "))
rest_time = int(input("Введіть час відпочинку = "))

while (work_time != 0):
    sleep(1)
    work_time -= 1
    print("До перерви залишилось ", work_time)
        
while (rest_time != 0):
    sleep(1)
    rest_time -= 1
    print("Час до наступої вправи", rest_time)
```

PS. `import *` лучше не делать. Если у вас будет много модулей, то потом запутаетесь, откуда какая функция; а если в разных модулях будут функции с одинаковыми именами, то функция из более позднего импорта перепишет предыдущую. В данном случае лучше просто `from time import sleep`, если уж вам так не хочется писать `time.sleep(1)`.

Comment: Благодарю, уже сам разобрался и хотел удалить вопрос